# For Loop on array from dynamic API in JSON format within template literals

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, api, for-loop

Trying to do all of this with as much vanilla Javascript as possible without needing React, Angular or anything else. I'm rendering the HTML contents through my JS file. How do I do a for loop within the template literals ( ` )? I cannot get a loop working and I need it for live data display. With the code you see on the JS file I manually put in a 0 index to get the first astronaut from the array and it works and displays fine.

This is my JS file.

```
const apiData ={
    url: 'http://api.open-notify.org/astros.json'
}

const {url} = apiData
const apiUrl = `${url}`

fetch(apiUrl)
    .then( (data) => data.json() )
    .then ( (astronauts) => createHtml(astronauts) )

const createHtml = (data) => {
    console.log(data)
    const html = `
    <div> 
        Total People In Space: ${data.number} <br>
        Names: ${data.people[0].name} <br>
        Craft: ${data.people[0].craft}
    </div>
    `
    const astronautDiv = document.querySelector('.astronaut')
    astronautDiv.innerHTML = html
}
```

Here is the latest contents from the API in its JSON format.

```
{"number": 3, "people": [{"craft": "ISS", "name": "Chris Cassidy"}, {"craft": "ISS", "name": "Anatoly Ivanishin"}, {"craft": "ISS", "name": "Ivan Vagner"}], "message": "success"}
```

Heres my HTML file.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Space</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="static/css/styles.css">
    <script src="static/js/main.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="astronaut"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: What is expected display structure for multiple names and crafts?

Comment: Trying to have multiple divs being created automatically with each new loop. A single div for each astronaut + craft.

Comment: I edited my answer to put each astronaut + craft inside a div

Comment: Note that explanation can still be interpreted several ways. Best to edit question with an actual html example for clarity

Comment: Brilliant!! Thank you @JannesCarpentier. It works perfect. You the man.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using .map and .join, we can construct a string within the template literal

```js
const JSONDATA = {"number": 3, "people": [{"craft": "ISS", "name": "Chris Cassidy"}, {"craft": "ISS", "name": "Anatoly Ivanishin"}, {"craft": "ISS", "name": "Ivan Vagner"}], "message": "success"}

const createHtml = (data) => {
    const html = `
    <div> 
        Total People In Space: ${data.number} <br>
        ${data.people.map(x => `<div>Name: ${x.name}, Craft: ${x.craft}</div>`).join("")}
    </div>
    `
    const astronautDiv = document.querySelector('.astronaut')
    astronautDiv.innerHTML = html
}

createHtml(JSONDATA);
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Space</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="static/css/styles.css">
    <script src="static/js/main.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="astronaut"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: If you click on `<>` in answer editor you can make this a runnable stack snipped here in the page

Answer (score 1):

If you set the `innerHTML` of an element, it will wipe out any previous `innerHTML` (such as other astronauts).

To add several elements inside your div, **you can use the **[`insertAdjacentHTML`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/insertAdjacentHTML)** method**, like:

```js
const
  astronautsDiv = document.querySelector('.astronaut'),
  myData = simulateFetchAndParse();
insertNewHtml(myData);

function insertNewHtml(data){

  // Inserts astronaut count
  const numberSpan = `<span>Total People In Space: ${data.number}</span>`;
  astronautsDiv.insertAdjacentHTML("beforeend", numberSpan);

  // Inserts individual astronaut information
  for(let person of data.people){
    const personDiv = `
      <div class="person"> 
          <div>Name: ${person.name}</div>
          <div>Craft: ${person.craft}</div>
      </div>
      `;
    astronautsDiv.insertAdjacentHTML("beforeend", personDiv);
  }
}

function simulateFetchAndParse(){
  const data = {
    number: 2,
    people: [
      { name: "Tasha Yar", craft: "Enterprise" },
      { name: "Buzz Lightyear", craft: "None" }
    ]
  };
  return data;
}
```

```css
.astronaut{ margin: 1em 0 0 1em; padding: 1em 0.5em 0 0.5em; border: 1px solid grey; }
.person{ margin: 1em 0; }
```

```html
<div class="astronaut"></div>
```

**Alternatively, you could use a series of [`createElement`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/createElement) and [`.appendChild`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/appendChild) calls** (which avoids the use of template literals where malformed HTML could fail at runtime).

The code would look more like this:

```js
const
  astronautsDiv = document.querySelector('.astronaut'),
  myData = simulateFetchAndParse();
insertNewHtml(myData);


function insertNewHtml(data){

  // Makes a span with some text, and appends it to our container
  const numberSpan = document.createElement("span");
  numberSpan.textContent = `Total People In Space: ${data.number}`;
  astronautsDiv.appendChild(numberSpan);

  for(let person of data.people){

    // Makes three new divs (`personDiv` will contain the other two)
    const
      personDiv = document.createElement("div"),
      nameDiv = document.createElement("div"),
      craftDiv = document.createElement("div");

    // Sets some text and a class
    nameDiv.textContent = `Name: ${person.name}`;
    craftDiv.textContent = `Craft: ${person.craft}`;
    personDiv.classList.add("person"); // So the CSS can style this div
   
    // Adds the two divs to `personDiv`, and adds `personDiv` to our container
    personDiv.appendChild(nameDiv);
    personDiv.appendChild(craftDiv);
    astronautsDiv.appendChild(personDiv);
  }
}

function simulateFetchAndParse(){
  const data = {
    number: 2,
    people: [
      { name: "Tasha Yar", craft: "Enterprise" },
      { name: "Buzz Lightyear", craft: "None" }
    ]
  };
  return data;
}
```

```css
    .astronaut{ margin: 1em 0 0 1em; padding: 1em 0.5em 0 0.5em; border: 1px solid grey; }
    .person{ margin: 1em 0; }
```

```html
<div class="astronaut"></div>
```

Comment: I like this as well. Explain further how you would use the createElement and appendChild? I would be interested.

Comment: That's awesome. I may play around with this code as well and see which solution works out better. That's the beauty of programming right? You can make similar things in so many different ways. :D